# Slot as method of a locally instantiated class is never called

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals, qt-slot

I have a list of mp3 files that I'm trying to play through pygame whenever different buttons are pressed (one file per button). Since there is a variable number of those files, I'm simply implementing a for loop, and I have an `AudioPlayer` class that I instantiate each time as follows:

```
import sys, pygame
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class AudioPlayer(QObject):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        super().__init__()
        self.filename = filename
        print("Created " + filename)

    def play(self):
        print("Playing " + self.filename)
        pygame.mixer.music.load(self.filename)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

class Session(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainWid = QWidget(self)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainWid.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWid)
        self.show()

        pygame.mixer.init()

        filenames = [r'C:\...\file1.mp3', r'C:\...\file2.mp3']

        for filename in filenames:
            playButton = QPushButton('Play', self)
            localPlay = AudioPlayer(filename)
            playButton.clicked.connect(localPlay.play)
            self.vbox.addWidget(playButton)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Session()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My problem is simply that the files do not play when I press the button, neither does the message get printed at all; it's like the slot never gets called:

```
admin@home> python main2.py
Created C:\...\file1.mp3
Created C:\...\file2.mp3
admin@home>
```

If I play the files manually outside of the loop, like this, it works:

```
class Session(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        # ...

        filenames = [r'C:\...\file1.mp3', r'C:\...\file2.mp3']

        pygame.mixer.music.load(filenames[0])
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

As you can see, I made sure AudioPlayer inherited QObject and called `__init__`, so I believe it should be able to receive signals. So what is going on here? Is it a local variable issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that the `AudioPlayer` objects created in the loop are local variables, so when they finish running the constructor they are deleted from memory. There are 2 possible solutions, the first is to make them attributes of the class, or the second is to pass them a parent since they inherit from `QObject`, I will use this second method:

```
class AudioPlayer(QObject):
    def __init__(self, filename, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.filename = filename
        print("Created " + filename)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def play(self):
        print("Playing " + self.filename)
        pygame.mixer.music.load(self.filename)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

class Session(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainWid = QWidget(self)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainWid.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWid)
        self.show()

        pygame.mixer.init()

        filenames = [r'C:\...\file1.mp3', r'C:\...\file2.mp3']

        for filename in filenames:
            playButton = QPushButton('Play', self)
            localPlay = AudioPlayer(filename, self)
            playButton.clicked.connect(localPlay.play)
            self.vbox.addWidget(playButton)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Session()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, this is what I assumed. Just a few questions if you don't mind:
1. Is the decorator necessary here on `play`? What is its function, is it purely indicative?
2. I don't know if this has to do with the fact I'm using Python 3, but `*args` is apparently not defined. If I replace it and simply use `super().__init__(self, parent=parent)`, I still get an error: `RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type AudioPlayer was never called`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @pie3636 The second was a typographical error, I corrected it. the decorator is not only indicative, this helps to improve the execution time and memory consumption of the application, to know about it read the following: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSlot